# Retrieving only the names from an xml file and putting them into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, split

// https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

// I am given the above xml file which has menu item names along with other things (price, calories, etc.) and I need to put only the names into an array using JavaScript coding. I'm using repl.it, and I already saved the file as a .xml on the side of my program. I just need to know how to extract only the names into an array. For example, the array should look like: [Belgian Waffles, Strawberry Belgian Waffles, (and so on)].

// In addition, I need to put the calories, the price, and the other stuff in separate arrays but I'm sure if I learn how to make an array for one thing I can do the other arrays too.

// In the past, I made this code to retrieve scores from a file with a list of scores (open repl.it link from the comments to see it in action):

```
// This program uses a file which has 6 peoples scores to calculate and display the max., min., and ave. scores and also puts them in an array. The program reads the file, trims out the strings so only the numbers are left & converted to numbers, limits the average score to the hundreths place, and verifies the file exists. The number of scores can be changed from 6 and the program would still work.
// Reference(s): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp
// https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrays-finding-the-minimum-maximum-sum-average-values-f02f1b0ce332
// Repl.it link: https://repl.it/live/AFSloyKSNJQjlA

main();

function main() {
    var filename = "scores.txt";

    if(!fileExists(filename)) {
        console.log(`File ${filename} is missing.`)
        return
    }

    var scores = [];
    var scores = readFile("scores.txt");
    console.log(scores);

    var maximum = getMax(scores);
    console.log("Maximum score: " + maximum)

    var minimum = getMin(scores);
    console.log("Mininum score: " + minimum);

    var sum = getSum(scores);

    var ave = sum / scores.length;
    var ave = ave.toFixed(2);
    console.log("Average score: " + ave);
}

function fileExists(filename) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    return fs.existsSync(filename);
}

function readFile(filename) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var scores = [];

    var contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    lines = contents.split('\n');

    for (var index = 0; index < lines.length; index++)  {
        var pos = lines[index].indexOf(',') + 1;
        var scoreStr = lines[index].substring(pos).trim();
        var score = Number(scoreStr);
        if (!isNaN(score)) {
          scores.push(score);
        }
    }

    return scores;
}

function getMax(scores) {
    scores.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
    var maximum = scores[0];

    return maximum;
} 

function getMin(scores) {
    scores.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    var minimum = scores[0];

    return minimum;
}

function getSum(scores)  {
    return scores.reduce(function(a,b){
      return a + b
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go about this. If you have a string of the XML you need to run through, and all you need is the contents of a single tag type, you can run that string through this regular expression to get what you need:

```
// xmlString is a string with the whole XML document in it
const foods = xmlString.match(/(?<=<name>)[A-Za-z ]+(?=<\/name>)/g);
```

If you want to get it by traversing the XML DOM, you can use JavaScript's standard DOM manipulation tools, like this:

```
const foodTagList = document.querySelectorAll('food name'); // selects all name nodes under food nodes
const foodList = [];
foodTagList.forEach((el) => foodList.push(el.innerHTML)) // can't use .map because foodTagList isn't an array
console.log(foodList); //prints the list of foods in array form
```

Finally, if you have the XML in string form and you want to do DOM traversal, you can run it through [DOMParser's `parseFromString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then use the instructions for DOM traversal above.